# Нужно сделать контекстное меню таким же как popup menu

Tags: android, style, design

У меня имеется стиль для меню

```
    <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.AppTheme</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/ItemMenu.AppTheme</item>

</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/menuFon</item> 
</style>


<style name="ItemMenu.AppTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Проблема такова что `ItemMenu.AppTheme` применяется как для `popupMenu` так и для `contextMenu`, А вот  `PopupMenu.AppTheme` Применяется только для `popupMenu`.

Подскажите как написать один стиль для всех меню?